# How to connect android to MySql database server?

Tags: android

In my project, I have to connect an Android mobile phone to a remote MySQL database server, to insert data to the database and get the data back later.

However, it seems that Android OS only supports the SQLLite database that works LOCALLY inside the phone.

Does anyone know how to connect an Android phone to a remote MySQL (or MSSQL, or Oracle) database server ?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a web service to do so. [An example here.](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/8339-connect-android-mysql-database-tutorial.html)

Comment: you need not expect android to provide... thats the reason they hava incorporated few of java packages too... you can do it using java..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to access the database using some sort of Remote Method Invocation (RMI).

My personal recommendation is to create a RESTful HTTP interface to your MySQL database on the server.  This may be a bit more work, but is preferred for its ease of use and compatibility with any system (that can make an HTTP request that is).

Essentially, you should create HTTP endpoints to Create, Read, Update, Delete (CRUD) data from your MySQL database on your server.  Your Android client would then make calls to these HTTP endpoints to perform the corresponding CRUD operations.  Of course you do not need to do the typical CRUD operations, you can make your endpoints interact with the database however you wish.

Like I said, a big advantage to this is how extensible it is.  You can create another client, on another system, in another language, and all you need to do is make the proper HTTP call.

Comment: great answer Mr.Nicholas How to create RESTful HTTP interface to MySql database.pls help me

Comment: Here is some reading about what REST is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services  And I would use Spring 3 MVC to implement my REST interface:  http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

try using Jdbc... for more read this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/package-summary.html