# How to get and put MS SQL SERVER database in android?

Tags: android

I want to connect my Android app to MS SQL database and fetch data from there. The database is on a remote server. I'm using Windows XP and have no idea about how to connect my app to a database. Some says webservice others say directly from the app. I'm confused. If anyone could provide me step by step guide, it would be highly appreciated. I know many tools like Rest, Soap and tomcat server but don't know how any of them works or how to get started. The database contains video URLs and I want to fetch a URL from the database and stream the video on my Android phone via URL.
PS: I want my webservice to be in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect android to MySql database server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936312/how-to-connect-android-to-mysql-database-server)

Comment: Have you tried searching SO and google? Because this is quite an easy thing to find tutorials on.

Comment: Did you find a good solution? I see you're pretty new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps you to get better answer on sucesive questions

Answer (score 1):

That what you whant to do is not a really good option as @ammcom says. It is better to have a Web Service as a middleware. You can try [Dream Factory](http://www.dreamfactory.com/), a service that automatically generates a Web API based on your database tables.

Nevertheless, you can also try a third party service as [Zumero](http://zumero.com/). This will sync your SQL Server databases whit a Sqlite database on your device.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to let your app connect directly to a database server as it raises a lot of security and scaleablity issues.

The best solution is to use a web server as a middleware between your android app and the Sql server database.

The web server is able to connect to the database and your app should contact the web server to exchange the data, you can use web services and many other techniques to do this.

This way the web server will be responsible for the handling requests from users which is better than allowing database server to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your server must implement the same api (ex rest), see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer